# How can I hide or disable text box after remaining time is over in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am building an auction website in php. I have calculated remaining time till an auction is live. The remaining time is calculated as `$remaning = $date - time();` where `$date` is the last date till auction of a product is live and it is fetched from the database using mysqli as shown below

```
<?php
if ($stmts = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT end_date FROM products WHERE pid = ?')) {
    $stmts->bind_param("i",$pid); 
    $stmts->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmts->bind_result($endDate); // get variables from result.
    $stmts->fetch();
    $stmts->close();

    $date = strtotime($endDate);
    $remaning = $date - time();
}
?>
```

I am accepting bidding amount through a text box in my page as shown below.

```
<form ...>  <!-- Form to submit bidding amount starts here -->
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Bid Price" name="bid_price" id="bid_price" title="Enter your Bid for auction" required />
    <input type="submit" class="sbmt"  name="bidsubmit" id="bidsubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>     <!-- Form ends here -->
```

How can I make that text box having id bid_price disabled or hide it after remaining time is over, so that no user can bid after that.

Comment: Can you show some code ? The bare minimum strip down your code to show something people can assist you with.

Comment: do not forget the situation where the user opens the form when there is time left, and then submit when time is over. This will happen because of snipe bids

Comment: Martijn thanks that was an essential part to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you've provided I can simply suggest using a condition as to whether the date is after `now` like so:

```
$date = DateTime('now');
$date->modify('+ 2 day');//testing negative

if ($date > DateTime('now')) {
    //show form
} else {
    //auction has ended
}
```

In the snippet above if you set the `modify` function to `- 1 days` the form will not show! Yeyyyyys

Note that I've set the operator to `>` rather than `>=` so that the form does not show exactly when the action is set to end. 
Another thing to bear in mind is timezones! But this shouldn't matter too much in your question?

**Furthermore**

Being a lover of packages in the packagist sense there is a package called Carbon which I think is really cool and simple to use.

```
if ($date->lt(Carbon::now()) {
}
```

It also has some cool features for date formatting and interval formatting. In this scenario I'd recommend using the `diffForHumans` method which gives some cool output like `2 days`, `30 seconds ago`. There's probably a method or parameter you can set to say `Ends in 30 seconds time`

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an if statement like
(pseudo code):

```
if (remainingTime <= 0) {
//auction ends
//html + php code here
?>

<input type="text" placeholder = "Auction Ended" name="bid_price" id="bid_price" title="Auction has ended" required disabled/>

}else{

<input type="text" placeholder="Bid Price" name="bid_price" id="bid_price" title="Enter your bid price" required/>

}
```